# gridExtra::marrange(): order plots by row

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

Given:

```
library(ggplot2)
l <- list(1:6)
for(i in 1:6){
  l[[i]] <- ggplot(data=data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)) +
    geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    ggtitle(i)
}
ml <- marrangeGrob(l, nrow=3, ncol=2)
ml
```

I get the plots ordered by column, that is:
1  4
2  5
3  6

but I want them arranged by row:
1  2
3  4
5  6

I've tried with byrow=TRUE, but it has no effect. How could I arrange the plots by row?

Comment: Is the `layout_matrix`-argument of `grid.arrange()` an option for you? I thinnk the same is usable in `marrangeGrob()` too, i.e. `marrangeGrob(l, layout_matrix =matrix(c(1:6), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments you can specify the order via the `layout_matrix=` argument, i.e. use the `byrow = TRUE` argument of `matrix()`.

Note: I switched to `lapply` to create the `list` of charts.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

l <- lapply(1:6, \(i) {
  ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    ggtitle(i)
})

ml <- marrangeGrob(l,
  layout_matrix = matrix(
    seq_len(3 * 2),
    nrow = 3, ncol = 2,
    byrow = TRUE
  )
)

ml
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. I just do not understand the " \ (i) " syntax, but this is another issue.

Comment: Nothing special. `\(i)` = `function(i)`. Was introduced in R 4.X.Y. (: